# Multifile upload is not working when form cloning with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, file, upload, clone

I have to generate multiple dynamic forms. These forms contains file input element. I have to upload multiple files. For dynamic form generation I used Jquery clone method , for multiple file upload I have used Jquery fyneworks plugin (http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/).

Whenever I clone the form I will assign ids dynamically. After cloning the form the file plugin is not working properly. It always adding to first form even though I am assigning ids dynamically.

I have created simple test scenario with following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='jquery-1.6.1.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src='jquery.MultiFile.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
 <script src='jquery.blockUI.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

 <script>
 var i=0;
 $(function(){
    //$("#div0").hide();
 });

       function addMoreForms(){
            i++;
            var x = $("#div0").clone(true);//.insertAfter($("#myForm"));
            $(x).attr("id", "div"+i);
            $(x).find("#myForm0").attr("id","myForm"+i);
            $(x).find("#file0_wrap").attr("id","file"+i+"_wrap");
            $(x).find("#file0_wrap_list").attr("id","file"+i+"_wrap_list");
            $(x).find("#file0").attr("id","file"+i).attr("name","file"+i).attr("class","multi");
           //$("#myForm").append('<input type="file" name="files[]" class="multi"/>')
            $(x).show();
            $(x).insertAfter('#div'+(i-1));
       }

 </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="div0">
<form id="myForm0" action="your-action">
    <input id="file0" type="file" name="file0" class="multi" maxlength="3"/>
</form>
</div>
<div>
 <a href="#" onclick="addMoreForms()">Add More</a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You make things complicate. you want to add more files to upload, why don't you use the simple code? why you have to use plugin to do it?

Here is my simple code to add more files to upload :

```
<script>
    var i=0;
    function addMoreForms(){
        i++;
        var $lastDiv = $("#div"+(i-1));
        var $div = $("<div/>").attr("id","div"+i).insertAfter($lastDiv);
        var $input = $lastDiv.find("input").clone();
        $input.appendTo($div);
    }
</script>

<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="your-action">
    <div id="div0">
        <input type="file" name="file[]" class="multi" />
    </div>
    <div id="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Upload " />
    </div>
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="addMoreForms()">Add More</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used plugin because I have to limit the number of files, size of the file and type of the file. I have to generate  these kind of forms dynamically. Each form can be able to upload up to 3 files, size < 10 mb and type of file.

Comment: Can anyone help me solving this problem.